# Symbolicate crash log

Tags: crash-reports

How do I read .crash file which is given by Apple against my .app. I have created build in build and archive mode and having its .dsym file as well. I am unable to symbolicate log.

How it can by sybolicated?

Comment: 'symbolicate' is not a word I've come across before. I'm guessing you mean "add debug symbols" perhaps? In which case we'll need to know what language and toolchain you're using.

Comment: Symbolicate is the term Apple uses to describe adding debug symbols back into crash reports from a stripped binary.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

You can import crash log (.crash) to the Xcode organizer and it will "hopefully" symbolicate that for you.
More info here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

**Option 2**

Also there are some apps in the Mac AppStore which are saying they will do that for you like this one

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/symbolicator/id705354958?ls=1&mt=12

**Option 3**

Or (for advance users) you can use "symbolicatecrash" command-line tool.

More info Here 
https://coderwall.com/p/ezdcmg